# Area 51 needs a "Galvanize" Button

Tags: discussion, feature-request, area-51

I think Area 51 needs a "Galvanize" button.

Some way of reaching out to the people who are following a site proposal to say "Hey, we are almost there! Go Vote!".

Obviously there are some difficulties, like who can click the button, etc.

You'd probably need some limits, to avoid spam. Something like "you can only click the button once per phase, or something".

Take the GIS proposal. The "hard core super dedicated" folks have managed to get us half way to the next stage. However, there are a lot of people who signed up to follow the proposal.

It would be cool if there was a way to reach out to them. Something other than the daily "these are the new questions / comments" that were posted, but more of a "hey! We are really really close now, and we need your help!".

Comment: Welcome to Meta Stack Overflow. Since this question has a down vote, let me point you to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-work

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, adding a comment to the proposal notifies all followers..

Answer (score 6):

If you need more support for your site, go out and bring the enthusiasts in. You're not supposed to continue relying on the people already in Area 51 to bring your proposal to light.

**These are your galvanize buttons:**

[image]

Comment: I understand the intention, but I think you're missing a potentially large group of people in your statement here.  See the comments in my answer to Joel's question last week.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53175/area-51-new-voting-system-results/53190#53190

Comment: (cntd, sorry..) I'm worried that people who are experts in a topic of a proposal but who are also not used to regularly visiting an online forum of the SE site nature could easily drift away.  I'm recruiting, but I want to make sure that once they're in they stay in.  I don't want to lose them before the commitment phase.  I would like to give them just a little reminder for them to stay active.

Answer (score 1):

To start a new site on Stack Exchange there should be many people who are dedicated to creating the site, not people who just vote for it once.

If there was such a button, the amount of people needed would have to be set higher.

Comment: I agree with you 100%. You are absolutely right. We want people who will be committed. But, sometimes people need a little nudge in the right direction. Right now, we don't have a way to give that nudge.