# How many on or off topic votes does a question need to count against questions needed now?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, area-51

I was just looking at [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2912/persian-information-technology-and-computer/3874#3874) question on Area51.  It has eleven great on topic votes, and no other votes.  The site still says they need ten questions of all sorts?  What's the new goal?

I'm worried about how much consensus you expect in a site before it can go to commit.  Even at just ten votes, you would still need twenty people who agreed *exactly* about the set of on and off topic questions to get a site into the commit phase.

**Math (Original 10 votes):**

- 10 Questions
- 10 votes for question (assumed)
- 5 votes per follower
- 100 votes / 5 votes
- 20 users

---

**Current Math (With above actual 30 vote limit):**

- 10 Questions
- 30 votes for question (current actual)
- 5 votes per follower
- 300 votes / 5 votes
- 60 users

This inclines me to wonder if the limit is actually 30 (which would require 60 users to be in agreement).

Comment: 10 + 10 is not 20 people, they can (and will) overlap.  And they don't have to agree *exactly*.  At least 60 followers are required anyway, and it's likely there will be more.  I hate to say it... but maybe we should restrict example questions even further: 3 per person and force the old questions to be winnowed down to the limit.

Comment: @The Cat: Persian IT has already met its quota for followers.  It also appears to have unambiguously on-topic answers, but the "good example" and "bad example" counts have not moved.  Perhaps The Team has moved those counts out of the "definition" phase.

Comment: @Robert: I think it more likely the thresholds are being evaluated in light of the voting limits.  I believe they should be focusing on controversial questions instead of the clear-cut cases anyway, but that's already on Meta elsewhere.

Comment: Is the on/off-topic vote count even *working* yet? I looked at several of the top sites, and they *all* show "10 on/off-topic questions needed".

Comment: @John It could be that it's just not working, but I assumed the limit hadn't been reached yet.

Comment: It's [greater than 16](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1425/geographic-information-systems/3447#3447) at least. If I had to guess, it's probably 25.

Comment: @Kyle, thanks, I wondered. Is there any official listing of the requirements? Not sure why that information should be hidden.

Comment: @John: I doubt it's intentional.  The site is in beta and things are changing quickly.

Comment: Ok, In [Persian IT](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2912/persian-information-technology-and-computer) we have a question with **18 off-topic vote** and another question with **14 on-topic vote** still no change on required on-topic/off-topic numbers.

Comment: In GIS we've reached **25** off-topic votes, still no change.  Sorry Kyle

Comment: @fmark it was just a guess, but I wasn't far off - the cutoff is 30

Comment: can a mod tag this FAQ at least? Otherwise, put it in the area51 faq page.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A question is considered on- or off-topic when it reaches 20 votes

Comment: Thanks Kyle, that's great work! You forgot the freehand circles though.

Comment: wow! If you have 60 members then you have 60*5=300 on-topic votes, so for 10 on-topic you will need 10*30=300 votes.

Comment: @Hameds see my answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52662/how-many-on-or-off-topic-votes-does-a-question-need-to-count-against-questions-ne/52830#52830

Answer (score 20):

We bumped it way up to 30, not because we actually think that's the right number but because we want to see how many votes questions are getting and then drop it down to the right number.  It's easier to lower it than to raise it without upsetting people.

**Update**

The final number (for now) is **20 votes**.

Answer (score 2):

Math based on actual currently

- 10 Questions
- 30 votes for question (current actual)
- 5 votes per follower
- 300 votes / 5 votes
- 60 users

That is way too many, it should be more like 15.

Comment: notice that the required number of followers is also 60, so the math evens out when you have a close knitted community (and the numbers have been lowered ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's a bug, if not, I think the restrictions are too high, limiting votes and upping the threshold, very difficult to reach 10 on topic and 10 off topic questions in my opinion.

No site has reached 1 in either category yet.

Comment: [Fewer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52708/) [questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52662/how-many-on-or-off-topic-votes-does-a-question-need-now#comment-123478) could really help this.

Comment: @The Cat I agree fewer questions would be better, but now we're looking at a question with 21 votes and it doesn't count?  I think the question at hand is still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Current threshold seems to be 20 votes.