# How come the Web Applications proposal still says it needs 10 on-topic and 10 off-topic questions?

Tags: bug, area-51

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many on or off topic votes does a question need to count against questions needed now?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52662/how-many-on-or-off-topic-votes-does-a-question-need-to-count-against-questions-ne)

The [Web Applications](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications) proposal on Area 51 is still saying it needs 10 on-topic and 10 off-topic questions before moving on to the next stage.

I've done a count and from what I can see there are two on topic questions:

[Exhibit A](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications/707#707) and [Exhibit B](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications/313#313)

and one off topic question:

[Exhibit C](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications/279#279)

there's another question with 10 off topic votes and 3 meh votes ([Exhibit D](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications/70#70)) but I'm not sure that counts.

That means the totals should be at 8 on topic and 9 (or 8) off topic questions still required.

Or am I missing something?

*NOTE: This is probably also true for the other proposals, but I haven't double checked those*

Comment: I think its the Broken-by-design or FUBAR adjectives (associated with the new voting system) which are causing this.

Comment: Looks like I was missing something!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris have a look at [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52662/how-many-on-or-off-topic-votes-does-a-question-need-to-count-against-questions-ne/52829#52829).