# On Area 51 what is used to measure definition progress now?

Tags: discussion, area-51

Prior to the voting process change many proposals had already made their discussion requirements and were 100% done with the first phase which was probably like setting your timer for two weeks and having it go off in two minutes instead.

After the voting system change even the [most popular](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1425/geographic-information-systems) site proposals with 160+ followers and almost as many questions are barely half way complete on the definition.

I am just curious, how is the system calculating *% complete* for the "definition stage".

Comment: I am pretty sure that getting all the followers, getting 10 on-topic and 10 off-topic questions defined should get you to 100 %.  I'm more so just curious as to what the system is using to figure this out.  In other words, are the followers worth 33%, 10 on-topic worth 33%, etc..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's 33% for each of the criteria on the proposal page:

- 60 followers
- 5 on-topic questions
- 5 off-topic questions

Right now very few questions are considered to be definitively on-topic or off-topic because [we set the threshold so high](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52662/how-many-on-or-off-topic-votes-does-a-question-need-to-count-against-questions-ne/52830#52830).  We'll drop it down when we're ready to let the first proposals into commitment.

Comment: Thanks for the details and the pointer to the supplemental discussion about the threshold.

Comment: @glowcoder you're right, I updated it to say 5 instead of 10

Answer (score 0):

All the votes on the questions were deleted. So those votes needs to be cast again. On every proposal it mentions what it still needs to go to the next phase. Most proposals needs more on- and off-topic questions.

Comment: Thanks Ikke.  For the sake of understanding I'm looking to see how the system will eventually arrive at 100% and what if any weights are applied to each component of a proposal definition.  It may be as simple as 33% to each main requirement for definition.