# how many votes are needed to make a question count towards moving to the next phase?

Tags: discussion, area-51

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many on or off topic votes does a question need to count against questions needed now?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52662/how-many-on-or-off-topic-votes-does-a-question-need-to-count-against-questions-ne)

20? a gabillion?

Comment: To recite the answer from the other post, it's currently 30 but will be reduced by the team at some point.