# When is a question counted as on-topic?

Tags: support, area-51, definition-phase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many on or off topic votes does a question need to count against questions needed now?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52662/how-many-on-or-off-topic-votes-does-a-question-need-to-count-against-questions-ne)

What are the criteria used to count a question as on-topic?
Does the question need to have X votes for "great on-topic example"?  What happens when the question has X votes as on-topic question, and Y votes as off-topic question?

Comment: Asked at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52662/how-many-on-or-off-topic-votes-does-a-question-need-to-count-against-questions-ne. However, the data changed since the answer was accepted - [20 is the correct number](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52662/how-many-on-or-off-topic-votes-does-a-question-need-to-count-against-questions-ne/55500#55500).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it needs 20 votes for 'Great on-topic example'.