# What is the purpose of the limit of 5 on/off-topic votes on Area51?

Tags: discussion, area-51, voting, site-proposal

I just found myself upvoting some on-topic questions in a proposal which were already upvoted, and then it wouldn’t let me get to the ones that actually needed attention.

What is the purpose of the draconian limit of only 5 votes? Isn’t that counterproductive to the idea of finding on-topic and off-topic questions in a proposal?

Comment: It isn't quite that bad, since you can change your votes when you feel the need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's historical.

During the first week of the Area51 beta, unlimited votes where allowed. Within the first week we had more than half of the users sitting with > 1K reputation and most proposals had unbalanced on and off-topic questions. The team realized that they need to balance this. Also some proposals moved from proposal to commitment in under 2 - 3 days, which was not the desired result.

Needless to say, the new system was implemented and all the user's reputation on the site at the time was recalculated to fit in with the new process. All votes where effectively removed.

Comment: Historic background: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52562/area-51-voting-reset-and-changes